# Document.querySelectorAll() not working

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get multiple elements with the same class name. I got no working results. What am I missing here?

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu__back"></div>
<div class="menu__back"></div>
<div class="menu__back"></div>
```

**JS**

```
 var backCtrl = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__back');

 backCtrl.addEventListener('click', function() {
   self._back();
 });

 };
```

Comment: Where is your JS in relation to the HTML, and how do you know you're not getting results?  You can't call `addEventListener` directly on the return value of `querySelectorAll`, it's a collection of nodes.

Comment: You're going to need some sort of loop to iterate over all the elements with that class. Oh, and the `querySelectorAll` is working just fine.

Comment: why not `getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: @scniro: Why not `querySelectorAll`?

Comment: Downvoter show your face please

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Voting is intentionally anonymous.  If they want to say something, they will, please don't try to call people out.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Well, but if you downvote an answer with a solution, maybe it's good to explain why downvote. In fact, is a recommendation of stackoverflow rules.

Comment: @squint this [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/getelementsbyclassname-vs-queryselectorall/174) seems to demonstrate qsa is slower. Do you think qsa is more verbose and intuitive when finding elements by class?

Comment: @scniro If you're only calling it once, the performance difference is likely to be negligible.  Also worth noting that they differ in return values - one is live, one is not.  It would be interesting to see a performance test that actually iterates the collection, as iterating a live collection may be different to a non-live one (I don't know either way, just speculating).

Comment: @scniro: I think they're both fine. A couple advantages of `qSA` is that IE8 supports it for CSS2 and a few CSS3 selectors. Also, it doesn't return a "live list", which depending on the situation has its advantages. Regarding performance, that's a matter of implementation.

Comment: @JamesThorpe @squint good points! It's surely so small to make a choice based off perf, but interesting nonetheless. I would usually opt for `getElementsByClassName`, just seems more pretty. Good argument? Not really, lol. The IE8 point of this would likely weight most important if that's a concern. I learned something here, good stuff

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector()` returns an object, but `querySelectorAll()` returns an array of objects. So you need to iterate to attach events:

```
for(i = 0; i < backCtrl.length; i++) {
   backCtrl[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
     self._back();
   });
}
```

Comment: Why downvote? This code works perfectly.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bzvjbr7v/ I don't know how many thousands of times it needs to be repeated that in JS, there are multiple issues with using `for-in` as though it was merely doing iteration of numeric indices.

Comment: I don't know what browser you're using, but in Chrome and Firefox errors are being thrown because you're using `for-in` instead of properly using a `for` loop or some other mechanism that limits iteration to numeric indices. The reason for the errors is that you're visiting the `.length` and `.item` properties, which clearly aren't going to have an `.addEventListener()` method.

Comment: Ok man, sorry if I disturb you. I will edit my answer to change it by a normal `for()`, but the idea is exactly the same, iterate  through the collection.

Comment: It exists to be used in a manner appropriate given its definition in the ECMAScript specification. If you want to reach all properties of an object, use `for-in`. If you're iterating only properties that are numeric indices, use `for` or some other for-like construct.